# After Christmas decorator bonus level, are residents and jobs unbalanced?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm hoping someone can point out the flaw in the following observation, and that the game works a little better than I'm thinking right now.

Before the Christmas decorator droid bonuses, getting all the levels of businesses and residences balanced the number of bitizens and the number of jobs.

The Christmas decorator droid bonus of Panna City Medicines adds jobs, but there's no way to add residences. Therefore, if you're at the max, you have no way to fill all your jobs; you're going to come up 3 bitizens short.

What have I overlooked in getting these jobs staffed?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct.  There are not enough bitizens to fill all of the jobs if you have Panna City Medicines.  Perhaps this will be fixed in an update.  Perhaps Panna City Medicines will disappear with the end of the cycle.  Regardless, for now, you cannot staff every available job.

Comment: It's notable that a shop will continue to sell a stocked product even if you vacate its stocking position. Therefore, it _is_ possible to keep all floors stocked by juggling employees, though you'll have at least 3 positions (necessarily the 3 Panna City positions at the moment, since they have no Dream Job employees so far) that can't have a Dream Job employee.

Comment: I love any solution that allows this game to rob me of any more of my free time than it already does!!!!  LOL!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.3.2700 there are 46 levels that can use bitizens, and 28 residential levels. This count includes both the special levels made available for the December 2013 and february 2014 events.

This will allow you to move in 140 bitizens for 138 jobs, so this issue is now fixed. Hopefully they will continue to include new residential levels whenever they add job levels in the future.